# Playframework 1.x : Get multi-level action path in template

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using `Play 1.2.7`.

I have a controller class `controllers.admin.module.Feedback` and I want to get it's full path in template, so I tried this:

```
@{admin.module.Feedback.list()}
```

But it generates the path `http://localhost:9000/admin/module.feedbacks/list` not what I expected(`http://localhost:9000/admin/module/feedbacks/list`).

How do I deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you modified the routes file for this URL?

You should try something like:

```
GET     /admin/module/feedbacks/list            admin.module.Feedback.list
```